# How to retry in python

Tags: python, exception

we know the standard `Exception Handling` in python:

```
def fun():
    a = 1
    x = 5
    ......
    ......
    try:
      print(x)
    except:
      print("An exception occurred %d", a)
    ......
    ......
    return x+a
```

I want to achieve that

1. if `try` fails, we will retry again immediately; if `try` fails second time, we will go to `except`.
2. if `try` fails, we will retry after 1 min; if `try` fails second time, we will go to `except`.

Could you offer me some reference of retry function in python?

Answer (score 2):

try the `retry` decorator from package `retry`

https://pypi.org/project/retry/

```bash
pip install retry
```

then

```py
from retry import retry

@retry(ZeroDivisionError, tries=4, delay=2, backoff=2)
def make_trouble():
    '''Retry on ZeroDivisionError, raise error after 3 attempts, sleep 2 seconds between attempts.'''
    print(f'trying {1.0/0.0}')



make_trouble()
```

Comment: seems this is what I want. Here `@` is Decorators? If try is a part of function and how to define the exception as I showed. Pls see my update.

Comment: could I ask how to pass a customized exception into retry, e.g. `except Exception as e:           a = a + 1           print("An exception occurred %s", a)`

Comment: try this:

```python
class me(BaseException):
    pass

@retry(me, tries=3)
def make_trouble2():
    raise me('huhh?')


make_trouble2():
```


Unfortunately, comments do not format the code correctly, you will have to re-format that to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of any retry function, but you can use loops to achieve almost the same thing

```py
while true:
    try:
        print(x)
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using that peice of code inside a function, why not call that function again if there is an exception?

I also guess that you don't want to return anything if there is an error so here is the code for 1st condition:

```
def fun(repeated=False):
    a = 1
    x = 5
    try:
        print(x)
        return x+a
    except:
        if times_repeated:
            print("An exception occurred")
        else:
            print("Trying again")
            fun(repeated=True)

fun()
```

Code for 2nd condition:

```
import time

def fun(repeated=False):
    if times_repeated:
        time.sleep(60)
    a = 1
    x = 5
    try:
        print(x)
        return x+a
    except:
        if times_repeated:
            print("An exception occurred")
        else:
            print("Trying again in 60 seconds")
            fun(repeated=True)

fun()
```

Comment: sorry  suppose there is a lot of code in the body, I just want to retry a part of code.

Comment: @user6703592 okay so you can then put that code in a function if it has to be repeated several times. Also look into `GOTO`'s from C# and try to find something similar in Python even tho it is a bad practice.